# Como setar um TextView com uma variável DOUBLE?

Tags: android, textview, double

Estou tentado setar a variável `txtMedia1` com o valor da variável `media1`. Fiz desta forma, porém o `Android Studio` indica que tenho que mudar txtMedia1 para `double` ou `media1` para `TextView`:

```
package com.app.jeffersonalencar.composicao;

import android.renderscript.Double2;
import android.renderscript.Sampler;
import android.support.annotation.StringDef;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class act_mains extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

    //Declarando variáveis de coleta de medida
    public EditText edtTxt1, edtTxt2, edtTxt3;
    //Declarando campo de visualização da média por parte
    public TextView txtMedia1;
    //Declarando botão
    public Button btnMedia1;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.act_main);

        //Setando os valores dos campos de coleta para as variáveis
        edtTxt1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtTxt1);
        edtTxt2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtTxt2);
        edtTxt3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtTxt3);


    }

    public void onClick(View V){
        double medida1 = Double.parseDouble(edtTxt1.getText().toString());
        double medida2 = Double.parseDouble(edtTxt2.getText().toString());
        double medida3 = Double.parseDouble(edtTxt3.getText().toString());


        double media1 = (medida1 + medida2 + medida3)/3;

        //Terminar a briga e colocar o valor no TextView
        String media2 = String.valuesOf(media1);
        txtMedia1 = (TextView) getText(R.id.media2) ;

    }


}
```

Realizando o que o `Android Studio` pede ainda sim da erro.

Comment: Agora após pressionar o botão de cálculo da média a aplicação fecha.. @Ack Lay

public void onClick(View V){
        double medida1 = Double.parseDouble(edtTxt1.getText().toString());
        double medida2 = Double.parseDouble(edtTxt2.getText().toString());
        double medida3 = Double.parseDouble(edtTxt3.getText().toString());


        double Bicipalmedia = (medida1 + medida2 + medida3)/3;

        //Terminar a briga e colocar o valor no TextView
        String valueDouble= Double.toString(Bicipalmedia);
        txtMedia1.setText(valueDouble);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Há varias formas de você fazer isso:

**Forma 1**

```
String valueDouble= Double.toString(media1);
txtMedia1.setText(valueDouble);
```

**Forma 2**

```
txtMedia1.setText(""+media1);
```

**Forma 3**

```
txtMedia1.setText(String.valueOf(media1));
```

**Forma 4**

Aqui seria basicamente igual a Forma 3, onde você pode usar o *format* para definir o formato que quiser, dependendo de quantas casas que que mostre depois da virgula. Veja:

```
txtMedia1.setText(String.format("%.2f", value));
```

Comment: Ack Lay, utilizei todas essas formas, porém ao clicar no botão para calcular a média a aplicação par de funcionar, alguma idéia do que seja?

Comment: @JeffersonAlencar é fácil resolver, porém sem você colocar o erro é difícil saber.

Comment: @JeffersonAlencar você colocou getText no seu TextView. Você tinha que colocar findViewById; por isso acontece o erro.

Comment: `FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.app.jeffersonalencar.composicao, PID: 3643
                  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
                      at com.app.jeffersonalencar.composicao.act_mains.onClick(act_mains.java:49)
                      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5637)
                      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22429)
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)``

Comment: ` at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)`

Comment: Segue acima o erro. @AckLay

Comment: @JeffersonAlencar o erro é por causa disso que comentei ai em cima, é só alterar que resolver.

Comment: Atualmente estou tentando usar esse método que me passou, já testei os outros, mas sempre ocorre o mesmo:
txtMedia1.setText(String.valueOf(media1));

Comment: Faz assim: txtMedia1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.media2) ; txtMedia1.setText(String.valueOf(media1));

Comment: Coloca Bicipalmedia no lugar de media1.

Comment: Error:(49, 49) error: cannot find symbol variable media2

Comment: Você tem q ver o id do seu TextView no seu XML.

Comment: O id do TextView é txtMedia1.
Se for assim: txtMedia1.setText(String.valueOf(Bicipalmedia));
        txtMedia1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtMedia1) ;

Não deu certo, fechou novamente

Comment: Primeiro vc tem que instanciar o TextView com o Id. Desta forma: txtMedia1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtMedia1); aí depois vc define um valor pra ele. txtMedia1.setText(""+Bicipalmedia)

Comment: Agora sim! Muito Obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

Utilizo uma conversão parecida em um app que possui desenvolvido. Adequando para o seu exemplo, ficaria da seguinte forma:

```
txtMedia.setText(Double.toString(media1));
```